# python module for nslookup

Tags: python-module, nslookup

Is there a python-module that's doing the same stuff as nslookup does?
I am planning to use nslookup on digging some information regarding the domain of a URL to be scrapped. I know I can use os.sys to call nslookup but I am just wondering if there is a python-module for this already.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 53):

Use the following code:

```
import socket

ip_list = []
ais = socket.getaddrinfo("www.yahoo.com",0,0,0,0)
for result in ais:
    ip_list.append(result[-1][0])
    ip_list = list(set(ip_list))
```

... or use a list comprehension as:

```
ip_list = list({addr[-1][0] for addr in socket.getaddrinfo(name, 0, 0, 0, 0)})
```

Comment: Socket doesn't appear to work very well for nslookup, especially if there are multiple domains for all the hostnames.

Comment: This works for me to get a list of IPs in a kubernetes statefulset

Answer (score 19):

You need to use [DNSPython](http://www.dnspython.org/)

```
import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('dnspython.org', 'MX')
for rdata in answers:
    print 'Host', rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference
```

Comment: This only returns IP, not fqdn

Comment: dnspython is a utility to work with DNS, /etc/hosts is thus not used. For simple forward DNS lookups, it's better to use socket.gethostbyname() (fount  on github of dnspython)

Answer (score 15):

the problem is that socket.gethostbyname() returns only one ip-address. nslookup returns as many as it has.
I use:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["nslookup", "www.google.com"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0].split('\n')

ip_arr = []
for data in output:
    if 'Address' in data:
        ip_arr.append(data.replace('Address: ',''))
ip_arr.pop(0)

print ip_arr
```

it will print:

```
['54.230.228.101', '54.230.228.6', '54.230.228.37', '54.230.228.80', '54.230.228.41', '54.230.228.114', '54.230.228.54', '54.230.228.23']
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use socket library http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

System function call is not a good practice in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Note that `socket.getfqdn()` can return the full-qualified name of a hostname. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.getaddrinfo#socket.getfqdn

For example:

```
python -c  'import socket; print(socket.gethostname()); print(socket.getfqdn());'
myserver
myserver.mydomain.local
```

But the result depends the `/etc/hosts` configuration. If you have:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       myserver  localhost.localdomain  localhost
```

The result of `socket.getfqdn()` will be:

```
python -c  'import socket; print(socket.getfqdn());'
localhost.localdomain
```

Oooops! To solve that, the only solution I know is to change the `/etc/hosts` as follow:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       myserver  myserver.mydomain.local  localhost.localdomain  localhost
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: While true and thorough, this looks up the local systems's hostname/fqdn. The OP asked how to lookup external dns names for site scraping. Still +1 for the info.

Comment: When I get FQDN's I get maybe half the servers with full FQDNs and the rest are just hostname. nothing. Why? Nslookup shows the FQDN on those nothing servers.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle, take a look at your `/etc/hosts`: you may find the answer yourself.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE we have multiple dns domains and thousands of servers in different domains, I'm trying to get the fqdn from a hostname, it's all coming back with just "hostname." My hosts looks like 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 I dunno what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to track down A records in AWS Route 53 using CNames. AKA `messaging.myCompany.com` to `moreSpecificMessaging.myCompanyInternal.com`

I also use Socket, but another rather hidden method.

```
import socket

addr1 = socket.gethostbyname_ex('google.com')

print(addr1)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname_ex

Comment: We can also call `socket.gethostbyname('google.com')`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname

Comment: gethostbyname() does not support IPv6 name resolution, and getaddrinfo() should be used instead for IPv4/v6 dual stack support.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are correct but here is what I would use [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#module-socket), it "provides access to the BSD socket interface. It is available on all modern Unix systems, Windows, MacOS, and probably additional platforms."

```
import socket

distinct_ips = []
# 0,0,0,0  is for (family, type, proto, canonname, sockaddr)
#change some_site.com to whatever your are looking up of course
socket_info = socket.getaddrinfo("some_site.com",0,0,0,0)
for result in socket_info:
    ns_ip = result[4][0]
    if distinct_ips.count(ns_ip)==0:
        distinct_ips.append(ns_ip)
        print(ns_ip)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code:

```
import socket
addr1 = socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
addr2 = socket.gethostbyname('yahoo.com')
print(addr1, addr2)
```

Comment: gethostbyname() does not support IPv6 name resolution, and getaddrinfo() should be used instead for IPv4/v6 dual stack support.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo apt install python-dns
$ python
>>> import DNS
>>> d = DNS.DnsRequest(server="1.1.1.1", timeout=1)                                       
>>> r = d.req(name="stackoverflow.com", qtype="A")
>>> [i['data'] for i in r.answers]
['151.101.129.69', '151.101.193.69', '151.101.1.69', '151.101.65.69']
```

Further details like ttl can also be accessed, plus this approach has the advantage of letting you specify which nameserver to use, instead of just using your system's default.