# Regarding the executable generated with py2exe from wxPython code

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

I have created a sample app from my real world app. I have used wxPython 3.0, python 2.7 and windows 7 64-bit OS.
The app is simple. It is a GUI with a text field where you can enter an IP address and then upon clicking a button, 10 nslookup queries will be made. The `gui.py` contains the GUI code and the `lookup.py` will contain the nslookup process code. After all this I used `py2exe` to create an executable. I successfully created an executable too.

**Problem**: When I execute my newly created executable the cmd console also appears/blinks while my app is running and performing nslookup queries! Why is this happening and how to avoid this? However if I execute my app via cmd by typing `gui.py` and hitting enter, no cmd windows appear during the nslookup process.

**Code**: All the code and the newly created executable is available for download [here](https://db.tt/l1dIuwlt), just to avoid any identation problems. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**gui.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import setupkwargs
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub as Publisher
from threading import Thread
import threading
import socket
import os
import sys

from lookup import checker

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        filePath = ''
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "test v1.0", style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,size=(550,250))
        self.Center()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.mainPanel = mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour('#EEEEEE')
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.myFont = myFont = wx.Font(11, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False,  "Arial")
        boldFont = wx.Font(11, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False,  "Arial")
        ipPanel = wx.Panel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.BORDER)
        iptextSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        iptitleText = wx.StaticText(ipPanel, -1, 'Please enter the IP and click the Check IP button to proceed!')
        iptitleText.SetFont(myFont)
        iptitleText.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        iptextSizer.Add(iptitleText, 0, wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, 10)
        ipText = wx.StaticText(ipPanel, -1, 'IP adddress: ')
        ipText.SetFont(myFont)
        ipTextCtrl = self.ipTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(ipPanel, -1, style = wx.TE_RICH, size=(303,24), name='ipTextCtrl')
        ipTextCtrl.SetFont(boldFont)
        ipTextCtrl.SetBackgroundColour('#FBFE99')
        ipTextCtrl.SetMaxLength(15)
        ipTextCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick)
        ipTextCtrl.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Please enter the IP address here."))
        self.ipButton = ipButton = wx.Button(ipPanel, -1, 'Check IP', size=(98,35), name='ipButton')
        ipButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onClick)
        ipButton.SetFont(myFont)
        ipButton.SetForegroundColour('#D6FDE2')
        ipButton.SetBackgroundColour('#05C354')
        ipButton.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Click to start the lookup process."))
        ipSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        ipSizer.AddSpacer(10)
        ipSizer.Add(ipText, 0, wx.TOP, 11)
        ipSizer.Add(ipTextCtrl, 0, wx.TOP, 9)
        ipSizer.AddSpacer(40)
        ipSizer.Add(ipButton, 0)
        ipSizerMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        ipSizerMain.Add(iptextSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        ipSizerMain.Add(ipSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        ipPanel.SetSizer(ipSizerMain)
        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizerA = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mainSizerA.Add(ipPanel, 1, wx.ALL, 2)
        mainSizer.AddSpacer(10)
        mainSizer.Add(mainSizerA, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        mainPanel.Layout()

    def logger(self, result):
        if result:
            pass
        else:
            self.ipButton.SetLabel('Check IP')
            self.ipButton.SetForegroundColour('#D6FDE2')
            self.ipButton.SetBackgroundColour('#05C354')
            self.iplistButton.SetLabel('Check IP List')
            self.browseButton.SetLabel('Browse IP List')
            self.browseButton.SetBackgroundColour('#05C354')
            self.browseButton.SetForegroundColour('#D6FDE2')
            self.ipButton.Enable()
            self.browseButton.Enable()
            self.stopButton.Disable()

    def onClick(self, e):
        widget = e.GetEventObject()
        widgetName = widget.GetName()
        if widgetName == 'ipButton':
            self.IP = self.ipTextCtrl.GetLineText(0)
            threadgetResults = getResults(self.IP, 'IP', None)

class getResults(Thread):
    def __init__(self, IP, code, filePath):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.IP = IP
        self.code = code
        self.filePath = filePath
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        if self.code == 'IP':
            blCheckerObj = checker()
            output = blCheckerObj.lookup(self.IP)
        else:
            pass
#---------------------------  MAIN  -------------------------------
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**lookup.py**

```
import subprocess
import time
import os
import sys
import random

class checker:
    def lookup(self, IP):
        self.IP = IP
        cmd = 'nslookup ' +self.IP
        print ' QUERY: '+cmd+'\n'
        for i in range(0,10):
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            self.out, self.err = p.communicate()
            print self.out
            time.sleep(3)
```

**setup.py** for building the executable.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

dll_excludes = ['OLEAUT32.dll','USER32.dll','COMCTL32.dll','SHELL32.dll',
                'ole32.dll','MSVCP90.dll','WINMM.dll','WSOCK32.dll',
                'COMDLG32.dll','ADVAPI32.dll','NETAPI32.dll','WS2_32.dll',
                'WINSPOOL.DRV','GDI32.dll','RPCRT4.dll','VERSION.dll',
                'KERNEL32.dll','ntdll.dll']

setup (
    name='Test',
    description="Script to test py2exe for packaging",
    version="0.1",
    windows=['gui.py'],#windows=[{'script': 'gui.py'}],
    platforms=["windows"],
    options={ 'py2exe': {
            'packages': 'encodings, wx.lib.pubsub',
            "excludes": dll_excludes,
            }
        },
    )
```

**py2exe log**:
[image]

**EDIT**: I would really appreciate it if any one of could test my script and post here if you observed any blinking/appearing of cmd console window, while the execution of my python script and as well as during the execution of the executable created.

**Solution**: I took the suggestion from [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393194/mike-driscoll) and finally decided to use [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) module instead of `nslookup` command, and now my problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the instantiation of wx.App to the following:

```
app = wx.App(False)
```

This tells wxPython not to redirect stdout/stderr to a window. Also I believe that `setup.py` file has an error as well. Try setting the `windows=` line to the following:

```
windows=['gui.py']
```

See also:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

Comment: Tried both options, unfortunately nothing changed. I have provided the log of py2exe in my question. Maybe it provides a clue to you. In log I see that many nodules and libraries are missing. As my exe is working fine, can I ignore these missing stuff. I think this is not the reason of my problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `print` statements in `lookup.py`? It could also be because you are opening the nslookup in a separate process. Maybe try `subprocess.call` instead of `Popen`. Or you could try redirecting stdout to a file or a file-like object.

Comment: I tried removing the print statements and also I tried using the subprocess.call instead of popen, still nothing changed. The cmd console appears/blinks during the executing of the executable created by py2exe. But the cmd consoles don't appear/blinks when I execute my python code.

Comment: I'm actually seeing the blinking when I just run the script itself. I also see it when I build it into an executable. I'm using wxPython 3, Python 2.7 on windows 7 32-bit

Comment: This is strange Mike. I don't see the blinking. I'm using wxPython 3, Python 2.7 on windows 7 64-bit. When I go home I'll test it on some other machine and see. Or I'll request other users to test this.

Comment: You might try using a Python module or package instead of nslookup. You could use socket, for example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297500/python-module-for-nslookup