# nslookup using server alternative in python

Tags: python, windows, nslookup

I'm looking for a python replacement for nslookup.

Other sources have pointed me towards socket.getaddrinfo(). However, this does not seem to allow me to specify a server through which to resolve a hostname, which nslookup supports and I require.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup 10.0.11.6 coolserver
Server:  coolserv.coolserver.com
Address:  10.0.1.1

Name:    the-host-name-i-want.blah.com
Address:  10.0.11.6
```

It is a requirement that I be able to do the lookup through "coolserver". Is this something `socket` or any other python library is capable of?

I'm aware that I can just call nslookup directly through subprocess.

EDIT:

As explained above, this is not a duplicate of [python module for nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297500/python-module-for-nslookup)

To my knowledge, `socket.getaddrinfo()` does not allow you to route the request through a server. I need to know "what does this server think my hostname is". Not "what is my local hostname".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python module for nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297500/python-module-for-nslookup)

Comment: Not a duplicate. As I said in the OP, `socket.getaddrinfo` does not allow you to specify a server, which is the functionality I need.

Comment: Are you looking for [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set specific DNS server using dns.resolver (pythondns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898363/set-specific-dns-server-using-dns-resolver-pythondns)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a resolver object and set the resolvers to the DNS servers you want to use:

```
from dns import *
resolver = resolver.Resolver()
resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8']
a = resolver.query('duckduckgo.com','A')
a.rrset.items[0].address #'54.241.2.241'
```

To do a reverse lookup do this:

```
r =reversename.from_address('50.18.200.106')
ra = resolver.query(r,'PTR')
ra.rrset.items[0].to_text() # 'ec2-50-18-200-106.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.'
```

Note `ec2-50-18-200-106.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` is a duckduckgo.com web server.

You may need to install dnspython.