# how to use subprocess to go over a list and run nslookup of each IP on the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if I can use subprocess to go over a list of IPs and perform "nslookup" on each of the IPs and capture the actual output, for ex.
I have a list here
ip_list = [10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3]

for ip in ip_list:
subprocess.???("nslookup", ip)

Comment: Is this already answered in this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751666/13799357](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751666/13799357)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python module for nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297500/python-module-for-nslookup)